# What OAuth providers are safe to use as Login authorization

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, authentication, oauth

Recently I've been doing some research into OAuth and OpenID/OpenId Connect and it's all just left me confused as to what is best to use and what is safe.

Originally I thought you could just use OAuth2.0 to log a user in (using their ID as a way of remembering the user) but then I found out that due to how the spec of OAuth 2 works, hijacking tokens would allow a malicious user to impersonate another person. Which is why it's stated that you shouldn't use OAuth 2 as authorization.

But then I have been reading that providers as such as google and facebook have decided to go away a little from the standard and ensure that such attacks are not possible. So my question, what OAuth providers are safe to use to gather a users ID to be used to log them into my service.

Also, facebook is offering another service called facebook login. From what I can tell it's OAuth but without the impersonation issue (obviously) AND the app creator cannot do other OAuth features as such as posting on behalf of the user without getting their app reviewed by facebook. Why would I use facebook login over OAuth which gives me all those permissions without review?

Thanks a heap everone

Comment: If you want to post on Facebook you have to get those permissions reviewed. There is no way around that

Comment: really! Probably didn't know this because I have only ever written twitter posting apps, I thought FB OAuth had it open :|

Comment: Facebook login _is_ based on OAuth – and as such, it uses access tokens as well, and if those get “stolen” somehow, then you have the same problem of course-

Comment: The problem there is barer tokens, What I am trying to figure out is what providers have opted to customise their OAuth implimentation and opt into the added extension of having a field for intended app. Facebook does this, so via sending the consumer this intended app string you can ensure another evil app isn't harvesting tokens and then using them to impersonate the user via giving the target app it's token.